# Private object properties

Tags: javascript, object, prototype, requirejs, private

I got a RequireJs module which instances another module and proxies some methods of it. I would now like to hide the module instance itself and only allow access through the proxy-methods.

```
define(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {

  var Proxy;

  Proxy = function(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
    this.mediator = new Mediator();
  };

  Proxy.prototype.on = function(event, callback, context) {
    this.mediator.subscribe(this.prefix + event, callback, context || this);
  };

  Proxy.prototype.off = function(event, callback, context) {
    this.mediator.unsubscribe(this.prefix + event, callback, context || this);
  };

  Proxy.prototype.trigger = function() {
    arguments[0] = this.prefix + arguments[0];
    this.mediator.trigger.apply(this.mediator, arguments);
  };

  return Proxy;

});

require(['proxy'], function(Proxy) {

  var proxy = new Proxy('sample:');

  // this access is secured and bound to the prefix
  // I cannot mess up with other events which do not belong to me
  proxy.on('log', function(message) { console.log(message); });
  proxy.trigger('log', 'hi hello');

  // unfortunately there still would be a hack to leave my event scope
  proxy.mediator.trigger('outerscope:test', 'blabla');

});
```

As you see it would be possible to access the internal used mediator object of the proxy prototype and to mess up with it...

I would now like to hide the mediator instance somehow but have no idea where.
I could store it in some normal variable inside the requirejs module callback but this would not work good with requirejs and could cause overlapping.

So what else can I do?

**UPDATE:**

```
define(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {

  var Proxy;

  var mediator = new Mediator();

  Proxy = function(prefix) {
    this.prefix = prefix;
  };

  Proxy.prototype.on = function(event, callback, context) {
    mediator.subscribe(this.prefix + event, callback, context || this);
  };

  Proxy.prototype.off = function(event, callback, context) {
    mediator.unsubscribe(this.prefix + event, callback, context || this);
  };

  Proxy.prototype.trigger = function() {
    arguments[0] = this.prefix + arguments[0];
    mediator.trigger.apply(this.mediator, arguments);
  };

  return Proxy;

});

require(['proxy'], function(Proxy) {

  var proxy = new Proxy('sample:');
  proxy.on('log', function(message) { console.log(message); });

});
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying `this would not work good with requirejs and could cause overlapping`? This is a great way to encapsulate your Mediator instance. It would be available for the Proxy but not outside. Exactly what you need.

Comment: @dfsq could you write an answer so I  can mark that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a typical example of encapsulation of variable within closures in Javascript. What you need is to define you mediator instance as a local variable in the same scope with the `Proxy`. This will allow the Proxy objects to have access to `Mediator` via closure but will isolate Mediator from the code outside your define-callback. So like this:

```
define(['mediator'], function(Mediator) {

    // Make mediator local scope variable
    var mediator = new Mediator(),

    Proxy = function(prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    };

    Proxy.prototype.on = function(event, callback, context) {
        mediator.subscribe(this.prefix + event, callback, context || this);
    };

    // ... rest of the code

    return Proxy;

});
```